# Django request array or not

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I find out that incoming request is a array or not?
For now I'm doing this approach

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if isinstance(request.data, list):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(many=True, data=request.data)
```

What could be the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to simplify this could this approach:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    is_many = isinstance(request.data, list)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(many=is_many, data=request.data)
```

In this example, I'm assuming that by not passing `many` in the first function call, it defaults to `False`.

Since you will always run the test `isinstance`, might as well call it first and use that as the value for the `many` parameter.

This way you only ever call the `self.get_serializer` once.

Comment: Thank you. I did this serializer = self.get_serializer(many=isinstance(request.data, list), data=request.data)